# Pandas - Python drop rows if Column contains multiples criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete the rows that do not contain "HW" or "CA" in column Vndr. This is my code:

```
data.drop(data[data.Vndr != 'HW' or 'CA'].index)
```

I am getting this error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 1):

You can using  `isin`

```
data.loc[~data.Vndr.isin([ 'HW' , 'CA']),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use

```
data[data.Vndr.str.contains('HW|CA'])
```

General approach

```
s="|".join(['HW', 'CA'])
data[data.Vndr.str.contains(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

it needs to actually be

```
... or data.Vndr != ‘CA’
```

Otherwise it doesn’t make sense

Comment: so I put the following code: data.drop(data[data.Vndr != 'HW' or data.Vndr != 'CA'].index)
& got the same error-did I miss something

Comment: Inside the [] indexing you need to put () around each binary operation:   [(data.Vndr != 'HW') or (data.Vndr != 'CA')].   Another way to get around that is using the Series.eq() and Series.ne().   [(data.Vndr.ne('HW') or (data.Vndr.ne('CA')].   Lastly,  you could use [~data.Vndr.isin(['HW', 'CA'])] where the tilde negates the Boolean index on Vndr.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting such rows, you can subset the rows which do not have such keywords.
You can work like this:

```
data = data[(data['Vndr'] != 'CA') | (data['Vndr'] != 'HW')]
```